# C# keyup event issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I use keyup event to add the functionality that by pressing enter cursor move to next control. This event works but I typed something in TextBox and then press enter cursor move to next control but the letters I typed in previous control is clear. I did not add clear function anywhere in my code.
Here is the code:

```
    private void nametextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.SelectNextControl(nametextBox, true, true, true, true);
        }
    }

    private void emailtextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.SelectNextControl(agetextBox, true, true, true, true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in the SelectNextControl method?

Comment: `SelectNextControl` is a [framework method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is it because your nameTextBox_KeyUp is passing nameTextBox to SelectNextControl? Should you be passing in a different control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `e.Handled` flag to `true` to prevent default key actions which I suspect are adding a new line to your control and hiding the text:

```
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.SelectNextControl(nametextBox, true, true, true, true);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

You will need to override `ProcessCmdKey`in order to prevent new lines from being entered and hiding your text. (Alternatively you can set your textboxes to be single line if that works for you). Otherwise, add this to your Window logic:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        return true;
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Returning true will flag that the default command should not be performed. This will affect all controls in your window however, meaning you will need to manually add newline functionality if needed.

Can I also suggest that you use the same handler for each of your key up events, unless you have anything different to add to each. You can do this by passing the sender as a `Control` instead of each control manually:

```
private void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      if(sender is Control)
          this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
}
```

Comment: I have created a demo app and it works for me. I have used two TextBox controls. Are you using text boxes?

Comment: I forgot to set my text boxes to be multiline. My apologies. I have found a solution. Please check my edited answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: But i found my error actually i selected textbox as multi line now i unchecked multiline in form1.cs[designer] level and it works.
Thanks to all :-)

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it. I have edited my answer anyway just in case you need multiline text boxes in the future :)